# unity inspector editor dropdown menu with images

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I want make dropdown menu to choose image from given. The problem is that image doesn't show in dropdown, only in already chosen. So I can see image only after I choose it from dropdown.

[image: here's editor screenshot]

I need every option in dropdown to have it's own little image so I can see which one I wanna edit.

here's editor code (in runeMaker.runeStorage.runes[i].preview we get simply Texture2D)

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

[CustomEditor(typeof(RuneMaker))]
public class RuneMakerEditor : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        DrawDefaultInspector();

        RuneMaker runeMaker = (RuneMaker)target;

        GUIContent[] imagesToChooseFrom = new GUIContent[runeMaker.runeStorage.runes.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < runeMaker.runeStorage.runes.Count; i++)
        {
            imagesToChooseFrom[i] = new GUIContent("rune " + i.ToString(), runeMaker.runeStorage.runes[i].preview);
        }

        runeMaker.runeToEditIndex = EditorGUILayout.Popup
        (
            label:new GUIContent("rune to edit"),
            selectedIndex:runeMaker.runeToEditIndex,
            displayedOptions:imagesToChooseFrom
        );
        
        if (GUILayout.Button("New rune")) runeMaker.NewRune();
    }
}
```

is it even possible to insert images to inspector dropdown?

Comment: Nope, I don't think you can in the build-in one - seems like you can either have text or icon but not both together  - would have to implement your own

Comment: Actually only icon would be acceptable. If you know how to do it please tell me

Comment: well I just did a quick test with a `new Texture2D` and it **seemed** as if that would work :D That was just a guess ... you could simply try and remove the `"rune " + i.ToString()` and only pass in the texture/icon

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears that it's not possible to make inspector dropdown menu show images and text altogether. So I get another approach. I make custom Editor Window, that has scrollview and bunch of images each with it's own button. Following script have to be placed inside Assets/Editor folder.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class CustomEditorWindow1 : EditorWindow
{    
    private Vector2 scrollPosition;

    [MenuItem("CustomEditors/CustomEditorWindow1")]
    public static void ShowWindow()
    {
        CustomEditorWindow1 window = CustomEditorWindow1)GetWindow(typeof(CustomEditorWindow1 ), true, "CustomEditorWindowHeader");
        window.Show();
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        scrollPosition = GUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPosition, false, true); 
   
        int runeIndex = 0;
        foreach (image in images)
        {
            EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();

            GUILayout.Box(image);

            EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical();
            if (GUILayout.Button("Do something")) DoSometheingWithImage(image);
            if (GUILayout.Button("Do another stuff")) DoEnotherStuffWithImage(image);
            EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();

            EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
        }

        GUILayout.EndScrollView();  
    }
}
```